# Masonry Overlap

Tags: jquery-masonry, masonry

I am noticing that my masonry page is creating overlap and unequal spacing. This isn't consistent and seems to happen sometimes, while at other times it works fine. In every scenario if I resize my window slightly, the mason() function kicks in and fixes it. I originally thought that it was an issue with having to wait for the images to load (around 30 at a time are loading), but I have already implemented imagesLoaded and see no difference. Can anyone point out my mistake?

```
<script>  
   function mason() {
    var $container = $('#dealcontainer').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.outerdeal',
            columnWidth: '.outerdeal'
        });
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry();
    });
   }
   function colorize()
   {
    $('.dealfilterli').click(function (event) {
           if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
               $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
           }
           $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
               if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                   $(this).closest('li').addClass("colorize");
               } else {
                   $(this).closest('li').removeClass("colorize");
               }
           });
       });
   }
   function InitInfiniteScroll(){
    $('#dealcontainer').infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : "div.pagination",
        nextSelector : "div.pagination li a",
        itemSelector : "#deals div.outerdeal",
        loading:{
            finishedMsg: '',
            img: 'http://www.example.com/img/icons/site/spinner.gif',
            msgText: '',
            speed: 'fast',
        },
    },function(newElements) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements );
                    $('#dealcontainer').masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
        mason();
    });
   }
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    InitInfiniteScroll();
    colorize();

   });
   $(window).resize(function() {
    InitInfiniteScroll();
    mason();
   }).resize();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue despite using imagesLoaded, and after a lot of trial and error I found that the problem can be solved with a setTimeout function. Here is an example from my project:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        masonryContainer.imagesLoaded(function() {
        masonryContainer.prepend(newPost);
        masonryContainer.masonry('prepended', newPost);
        });
    }, 500);
```

The 500ms timeout is arbitrary, so I would play around with that on your page to find the lowest possible value that still fixes your issue. Hope that helps!

Cheers,

Jake

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$container.masonry('reloadItems');
```

on mason() function and everything will be replaced in the correct position.